# Is it OK to compare PEPROCESS values?

Tags: c, windows, driver, filter-driver

I am "reviewing" some code that was written well before me and I'm noticing a pattern that I have some doubts about:

The result of the `PsGetCurrentProcess()` function is stored and then comparisons are made with that pointer (which is a pointer to an `EPROCESS` struct).
However, I'm not finding anything in the documentation, which suggests this function is guaranteed to return the same pointer each time. What is much more surprising to me is that this code has been apparently working for a long time.

Is this a bug, and would you recommend changing that logic to e.g. comparing Process IDs (Using PsGetProcessId)?

Comment: I am receiving a downvote without a comment. I find this quite disturbing - if someone would like to comment why this is not a good question or provide criticism, please do so, it is quite strongly encouraged by the site rules.

Comment: It might very well be a bug. I also think that your question is fine. It's one of the best i've seen so I too don't understand the downvote.

Comment: "*comparisons are made with this result*" on the pointer **value** returned?

Comment: @alk I just edited the question to hopefully better reflect that the *pointers* are compared

Comment: NMDV, but where is the rule about "it is quite strongly encouraged by the site rules."? Did not find that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

Comment: @chux From http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down : "Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing. Instead of voting down: [...] If something is wrong, please leave a comment or edit the post to correct it."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is pretty much correct. The documentation of `EPROCESS` makes it clear that there is one such object per process, and any `PEPROCESS` points to this. This means `PsGetCurrentProcess()` does't return a pointer to *an* `EPROCESS` but to *the* `EPROCESS`. And two pointers compare equal if they point to the same object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you provide a definitive source for this? While the documentation somewhat suggests it (by using **the** instead of **a**), I can't find anything else on this topic.

Comment: Self-evident, so unlikely to be explicitly documented.

Comment: (To clarify that: this is the sort of thing that in my experience Microsoft considers self-evident and are unlikely to explicitly document.  I didn't mean to imply that it *shouldn't* have been documented or that it was a silly question.)